# Распаковка zip архивов на PHP (русские название файлов внутри архива)

Tags: php, zip

Здравствуйте
Есть архив заархивирован на Windows, там есть файлы с русскими названиями.
Розархивация происходит через ZipArchive (на Linux)

```
$zipObject = new ZipArchive();
if ($zipObject->open(PATH_TO_QUEUE . '/' . $fileImportDirectory) === true) {
    $zipObject->extractTo($unzippedDirectory);
    $zipObject->close();
    unlink(PATH_TO_QUEUE . '/' . $fileImportDirectory);
}
```

Но после архива создаются файлы в которых удалены русские буквы.
Название архива типа: Б-0006754
Создается файл типа: -0006754 (без русской буквы "Б")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в разной кодировке имён файлов внутри архива и у юниксовой локали. Получите текущую локаль и перекодируйте имена файлов/каталогов в неё.

Comment: Это не ответ. Примеры кода бы увидеть.

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Причем даже при распаковке без указания имени файла в архиве, выгружались файлы с обрезанными названиями до пробела или знака препинания.
"Прайс-Лист" выгружался как "-Лист"
"Анализ Цен" как " Цен" - именно с пробелом спереди

Удалось сделать костыль тем, что перед распаковкой переименовал файл внутри архива на Латиницу функцией
$zipObject->renameName($oldName , $newName);